# Mouse gets stuck

Tags: mouse, touchpad

Just installed Ubuntu on an acer laptop. Everything was working fine. Now my mouse randomly gets stuck. I can left click and right click but I am unable to move it at all. Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper answer but I face the problem too.
 Whenever it happens try to open terminal with ***Ctrl+Alt+T*** and type **`xrefresh`** and enter. That will refresh your x screen without restarting the operating system. 
In that way I the issue get solved maximum times, hope it will help you.